# Link a button through CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, hyperlink

I have this Button CSS written in common for entire theme on all the sliders

```
.btn {
font-size: 13px;
padding: 9px 20px 12px;
margin: 11px 0px 0px;
border: 0px;
line-height: 19px;
white-space: nowrap;
opacity: 1;
left: 471.5px;
top: 292px;
transform: scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg);
visibility: visible;
}
```

I linked the text within this Button. I can access the link only when I click on the text over the button. But my requirement is the link to be accessed when I click anywhere on the button. I tried alot but no luck.

Please guide me.

Comment: You can just add class="btn" to your <a> element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think turning your `<a>` into a button will be more suitable that way you can change it into whatever way you wish and it will be clickable from anywhere  http://jsfiddle.net/7pr6ktzs/

```
<a href="#">button</a>
```

CSS

```
a{
display:block;
background-color:green;
width:200px;
height:200px;
font-size:50px;
border-radius:30px;
}
```

The `<a>` must be displayed in block other wise this won't work

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.btn {
font-size: 13px;
padding: 9px 20px 12px;
margin: 11px 0px 0px;
border: 0px;
line-height: 19px;
white-space: nowrap;
opacity: 1;
left: 471.5px;
top: 292px;
transform: scale(1, 1) rotate(0deg);
visibility: visible;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" class='btn'>
<input type="reset" value="Submit" class='btn'>
<input type="reset" value="button" class='btn' value='Save'>

</body>

</html>
```